# android, аутентификация

Tags: android, auth, room

Пытаюсь сделать вход и регистрацию в приложение. Хочу чтобы оно работало без взаимодействия с апи, и вопрос, как мне сделать так, чтобы пользователь, когда входил в приложение в первый раз - зарегистрировался, а в последующие входы в приложение экран входа/регистрации пропускался(так как он уже входил в прошлый раз), ну и к тому же вопрос, как к примеру, можно выходить из этой же учетной записи, то есть, чтобы в памяти приложения терялись данные под которыми пользователь входил.
Если вкратце, то каким образом дать приложению возможность запоминать токен входа, или что-тот в этом роде, и должно быть сделано без использования апи и с локальной базой данных(использую room)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я предлагаю воспользоваться SharedPreferences. Суть будет такова: когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку "Войти" и данные введенные ним совпадают с данными в БД то в настройки пишется переменная:

```
val editor = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_STORAGE, 0).edit()
editor.putBoolean("hasVisited", true).apply()
```

У вас в приложении вероятнее всего есть активность которая является стартовой и с которой осуществляется вход в приложение. В функции `onCreate()` этой активности нужно сделать проверку данной переменной:

```
sp = this.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_STORAGE, 0)
if (sp!!.getBoolean("hasVisited", false)) {
    val goToNextScr = Intent(this, YourSecondScreen::class.java)
    goToMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)
    startActivity(goToMain)
    finish()
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
} else {

}
```

Как можно увидеть из кода выше - вы проверяете если переменная true то переходим дальше незамедлительно если же она false то например у меня проверяется соединение с интернетом и дальше комплекс действий для входа по апи. Если вам никаких действий предпринимать не нужно то можете убрать блок else. Дальше - как удалить данные с которыми пользователь входил. Это я так понимаю аналог функции логаута вас интересует. Можно делать так:

```
fun logOut() {
        val editor = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_STORAGE, 0).edit()
        editor.clear().apply()
        editor.putBoolean("hasVisited", false).apply()

        val intent = Intent(context, LoginScr::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

кодом выше вы очищаете все настройки приложения и оставляете только ту которая отвечает за вход в приложение.